# Serialize for JavaScript apex

Tags: javascript, c#, json, json.net, json-serialization

I need to serialize some simple object from .NET to JavaScript...

But I've some problem with apex...

C# example

```
var obj = new { id = 0, label = @"some ""important"" text" };
string json1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
string json2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj,
                   new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() 
                   {
                       StringEscapeHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml 
                   });
```

JavaScript example

```
var resJson1= JSON.parse('{"id":0,"label":"some \"important\" text"}');
var resJson2= JSON.parse('{"id":0,"label":"some \u0022important\u0022 text"}');
```

Both parse give me the same error

> VM517:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position
>   23 at JSON.parse(<anonymous>)

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're pasting the generated string of JSON into a JavaScript string constant without escaping it further. Try

```
console.log('{"id":0,"label":"some \"important\" text"}');
```

You'll see `{"id":0,"label":"some "important" text"}` i.e. the "important" quotes are no longer escaped by backslashes. (And you'll get the same for your `\u0022` example too.) If you want to paste in the backslashes you'll have to escape them again:

```
var resJson1= JSON.parse('{"id":0,"label":"some \\"important\\" text"}');
```

The JSON you've generated with a single backslash would be fine if read from a file or URL, just not pasted into JavaScript as a string constant.

Comment: ok, now for develop i'm pasting it...
there isn't a  "c# way" to seriliaze in "pastable" javascript string?